# Collapse navbar not displaying links once collapsed

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to learn basic bootstrap/CSS/HTML. When my navbar collapses, none of the links are displayed when clicked on. I have them set up as images on the navbar, so I am not sure if that has something to do with it. Here is my code, thanks so much for taking a look!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>website</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bs-custom-file-input/dist/bs-custom-file-input.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">


</head>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-white justify-content-center">
      <a class="navbar-brand mr-0" href="#">
      <img src="images/logo.bmp" alt="" width="150" height="45" class="d-inline-block align-top">
      <button class="navbar-toggler ml-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar2">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="collapsingNavbar2">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-center">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/me/"target="_blank"> 
                  <img src="images/linkedin.jpg" title ="LinkedIn"
          width=30" height="30"></a>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="https://github.com/me"target="_blank"> 
                    <img src="images/github.png" title ="GitHub"
            width=30" height="30"></a>
                </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="images/resume.pdf"target="_blank"> 
                            <img src="images/resume.png" title ="Resume"
                    width=30" height="30"></a>
              </li>
          </ul>

      </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is home.css , if that makes a difference:

```
    body {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #dae0e6;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0.05rem 0.1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.cover-container {
    max-width: 60vw;
}

.nav-link {
    padding: 0.25rem 0;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    margin-left: 1rem;
    border-bottom: 0.25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.nav-link.active {
    color: white;
    border-bottom-color: white;
}

.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.navbar {
    /* min-height: 80px; */
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    /* (80px - button height 34px) / 2 = 23px */
    margin-top: 23px;
    padding: 9px 10px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are including the Javascript needed to make the navbar collapse function work. JQuery must come first, and then the Bootstrap JS file.

See here for more info: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: so simple. thanks so much for taking a look! That worked!